# Long query execute time to large MySQL table using 3 conditions and 1 order

Tags: mysql

**Database:** MySQL (InnoDB) ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.60, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

**forum_posts table size:** 3 million rows

**Main Query (3 conditions + 1 order):**

```
SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE deleted = 0 AND published = 1 AND 
show_homepage = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 25;
5 rows in set (12.56 sec)
```

**Query without ORDER BY (3 conditions)**

```
SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE deleted = 0 AND published = 1 AND 
show_homepage = 1 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 25;
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Query with ORDER BY and only 2 conditions in WHERE (deleted + show_homepage)**

```
SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE deleted = 0 AND show_homepage = 1 ORDER 
BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 25;
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Query with ORDER BY and only 2 conditions in WHERE (deleted + published)**

```
SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE deleted = 0 AND published = 1 ORDER BY 
id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 25;
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Why Main Query running time is about 12 seconds?
Table has indexes for all 4 fields (3 fields from conditions and 1 from order).

Also I have created computed index for 3 fields and for all 4 fields.
Nothing helps.

Please help to understand a reason of problem.

Comment: Maybe because it is first and next queries just pull data from cache.

Comment: You need to be doing cold testing my friend. Database cache helps you out here. Better yet, check your EXPLAIN plans.

Comment: Try your queries with [SQL_NO_CACHE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html)

Comment: The performance on subsequent queries has been answered. As to the original query; just because you have indexes doesn't mean they are optimal for your query or that your database is producing an optimal plan that uses them. Try adding multi-column indexes (order can matter) or using FORCE INDEX to test for improvements. As was mentioned, examining the execution plan is the only real way to identify where the loss in performance is happening.